# 64 Bit Excel ODBC query generates corrupt data

Tags: excel, odbc, ms-query

When trying to query from Microsoft Query and return the data to Excel, I am getting strange characters as shown in the attachment. It is returning some Chinese characters and some other unknown characters.

[Strange Characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXdVj.png)

When querying the data directly from Microsoft Query, and not returning the data to Excel, the data is displayed correctly. Also I have downloaded the ODBCTest application from Microsoft's github and data is returned correctly there as well. In my ODBC driver code, I am also just printing out the raw data right before the data is returned in the SQLFetch function, and I can see the data is correct.

If anyone is able to help explain why the data returned via Excel is different than the data returned via Microsoft Query, that would be great. We believe it has something to do with the encoding, but don't have any solid leads.

Thanks

Version 16.0.13530.20490 64 Bit Excel

Comment: Please provide a clear image

Comment: @AshwinBalani I attached a clearer image

Comment: Can you try debugging the code after the 10th entry, and observe what's going wrong?

Comment: @AshwinBalani I tried debugging, and I was able to print the raw values before sending them back to excel, and they were correct.